# How to publish 64 bit bundle app to google store with 32-bit .so files

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I've developed an Android app with Android Studio 2021 and have used some .so files.
When I debug the app it works successfully with this Gradle configs:

```
android {
    compileSdk 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2022"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        proguardFile 'proguard-android.txt'
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "x86"
        }
    }
    debug {
        ndk {
            abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "x86"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I decided to publish app on the google store, The store returned this error:

**This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.**

Then I did

1. add **"arm64-v8a"** to end of abiFilters line in release mode:

   abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "x86","arm64-v8a"
2. create new folder in jniLibs folder
3. copy .so files from  armeabi-v7a folder to arm64-v8a folder

The store error disappeared But a new problem raised :
When I generate APK file, the app crashes with this error

**No implementation found for int com.xxxx.xxx  at com.wifi.xxxx(Native Method)**

Can anyone advice what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to publish to PlayStore an .apk or .aab?

I've made it work using .apk with the following steps:

- decompile apk
- inside lib folder create a new folder called arm64-v8a
- copy the armeabi-v7a folder inside the arm64-v8a folder (yes, that way worked to me)
- recompile

in my case no need of those lines:
ndk {
abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "x86"
}

you can have a more detailed idea following this [Link](https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/decompile-recompile-and-publish-into-google-play-store-b4d5914cb38a)

Anyway, those days PlayStore require you to upload a .aab, so I'm currently looking for a way to make it work with .aab